# Meaning of "Walk my way"?

Tags: meaning

There's this sentence I don't get, in a song. So the words go something like:

> Walk my way, so we can get closer, closer
> Baby, come at me, I dare you
> Come after me, I dare you to.

In the rest of the song, the singer seems to talk to haters ("Say what you wanna say, talk is cheap. But you're gonna pay if you keep looking at me. You've got so much anger inside that a body could start a fire inside of me")

So it seems like 'walk my way' means "instead of talking about me when I'm not around, come and walk the same way as I do so that we can have some face to face confrontation".

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

"Walk my way" means "walk in my direction, come toward me, approach me." It's also pretty clear from the context. "So we can get closer... come at me... come after me."